# Cant connect to apache server on ubunu virtual machine outside the host machine

Tags: networking, server, ssh, virtualbox, apache2

I set up an apache server on my ubuntu virtual machine, but cant connect to it outside the host machine, on my phone, outside the virtual machine etc. I dont know if I have set up everthing correctly, as this is my first time doing something like this. I have tried portforwarding port 80 and 443, though im unsure about what IP to use where. On the port forwarding page, i am asked for a server ip and an originating ip, along side the start/end ports. What IP's should i use here?

I have also tried to disable the firewall on the host machine completely. When i try to access the server on the host machine through its static ipv4 address or localhost, it works. However i cant connect to it using that same ip on my phone etc, which is on the same network. Something tells me im using the wrong ip somewhere.

In the apache2.conf file it says "Include ports.conf" which then contains:

```
Listen *:80
Listen *:443

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listem 443
</IfModule>
```

As i said, im completely new to linux and servers in general. For now, i just want my server to display a simple php page showing the current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to connect to a VirtualBox instance, you will need to configure the network to use a "Bridged Adapter". This is done on the host as seen in the screenshot below:

[image: VirtualBox - Networking]

Once this is done, boot the virtual machine and confirm the IP address that was assigned to it. You can do this with the `ip` command as seen in the example below:

```
$ ip a

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:16:45:06:86:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.110/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute enp0s31f6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2402:6b00:3ed9:f300:fc3f:a893:ec64:92ea/64 scope global temporary dynamic
```

Here I can see the VM has an IP address of `192.168.0.110`. If I put this into a browser, then I will see a result from Apache.

If you are going to use SSL (port 443) with a virtual machine on a local network, you will likely need something that is self-signed or do a bunch of DNS busywork to use something from Let's Encrypt inside a self-contained network. You should be good with standard HTTP requests over port 80 unless you plan on exposing the virtual machine to the entire Internet.

Hope this helps you overcome some of the initial questions

Comment: Okay thanks!, so that means I dont need to put something in the "Originating ip" on the portfoward, as its an optional feature? I should i just put my version of that ip you found in the "server ip" box and use port 80?